# Average and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Consider a list of $k$ $n$-vectors $a_1,...,a_k$, and define the $n$ x $k$ matrix $A = [a_1,...,a_k]$.

Let the $k$-vector give the means of the columns, i.e. $\mu_i = avg(a_i)$, $i=1,...,k$.

Give an expression for $\mu$ in terms of the matrix $A$.

Would the matrix be

$\mu=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{a_{11}}{n} & \frac{a_{12}}{n} & ... & \frac{a_{1k}}{n} \\
    \frac{a_{21}}{n} & \frac{a_{22}}{n} & ... & \frac{a_{2k}}{n} \\
    ... & ... & ... & ... \\
    \frac{a_{n1}}{n} & \frac{a_{n2}}{n} & ... & \frac{a_{nk}}{n} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu=A\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n}\\\dots\\\frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$

Remark: $A_{ij}=(a_j)_i$.

Comment: The vector on the right hand should be a $k$-vector, I guess.

Comment: I was thinking that however, wouldn't it be a n x k matrix so it would look a little like
mu = (a11/n ... a1k/n) (a21/n ... a2k/n)

Comment: yes, explicitly $\mu=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a_{11}}{n}+\dots+\frac{a_{1k}}{n} \\ \frac{a_{21}}{n}+\dots+\frac{a_{2k}}{n}\\ \dots\\ \frac{a_{n1}}{n}+\dots+\frac{a_{nk}}{n}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would there be plus signs or without the plus ?

Comment: You're taking the average, there should be the plus sign.